# how to delete certain characters from a string in php

Tags: php, str-replace

For creating breadcrumbs i have a string as below:

```
$crumbs = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

This generates the following output:

```
/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm / c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b / folder1 / folder2 /
```

How can i eliminate these first characters from the output:

```
/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm /
```

so that it starts with the hash

Comment: Will it always be the first 2 elements or will it always be `/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm /`?

Comment: it will always be: `/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm /`

Comment: `str_replcace()` before `explode()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few easy ways to tackle this problem.

**Consider Replacing Prior to Exploding**

The first could be to simply perform your [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) call prior to the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function :

```
# Explicitly replace your input
$input = str_replace($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/','');
# Then explode as expected
$crumbs = explode("/", $input);
```

**Slice Off The First Two Elements**

Another option would be to simply slice your original array and remove the first two elements from it via the [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
# Explode your string into an array
$crumbs = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
# Trim off the first two elements of the array
$crumbs = array_slice($crumbs,2)
```

Comment: array_slice() is the only option if the first part (in this case '/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm /') can change from one request to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php):

```
$input = '/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm / c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b / folder1 / folder2 /';
$replace = '/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm /';
echo str_replace($replace, '', $input);
```

With your code the following should work:

```
$crumbs = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$replace = '/ sfm?dir=uploads / sfm /';
$crumbs = str_replace($replace, '', $crumbs);
$crumbs = explode("/", $crumbs);
```

A working demo can be found here: https://3v4l.org/QOm4S

Answer (score 1):

With explode you created an array so I would create a string or another array with the array data I want to be displayed

```
$crumbs = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

//For string

$breadcrumbs = $crumbs[2].$crumbs[3].$crumbs[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to remove the first characters before exploding the string. You can slice the array to remove the url parts you dont need.

Example code:

```
$crumbs = explode('/', '/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b/folder1/folder2/');

$result = array_slice($crumbs, 3);

// Do something with result.
```

Your code will still work even when the first parts of the url start with something else.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Or you can exclude this string while exploding the main string:

```
$crumbs = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$new_string = "";
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count ($crumbs) ; $i++){
    if ($crumbs[$i] != 'sfm?dir=uploads'){
        $new_string .= '/' . $crumbs[$i];
    }
}
return $new_string; //This is your your string
```